# Power Bi fields parameters connections

Tags: powerbi, visualization, slicers

I would like to create two bar charts with two parameter fields and I want to connect them both so that when I select one of the parameters from the first parameter it changes the slicer of the second parameter, so that the second bar chart will change accordingly[image]